# Can you sort a Case List View by date time of the latest received email?

Tags: case, list-view, email2case

I’ve been asked to mimic an email inbox in the case list view, can we sort email to case cases by the time the email was received, we can’t just sort by case number or open date as it needs to account for replies to cases and the reopened cases when a customer replies to a closed case.

I’ve been putting this off for a bit as I don’t think it’s easy/straight forward but I am hoping someone can help or confirm it isn’t possible without a custom page.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this "out of the box," but you also don't need a custom page. Instead, you just need a custom field and a bit of configuration. First, create a new DateTime field on Case for "latest email". Then, create a new Process Builder on Email Message to update the Case when an email comes in. Finally, you can create list views to leverage this new field. Note that you'll need to run an update against existing cases once to populate already existing records, but after you activate the process, this will happen automatically for future cases.

Comment: Thanks fox, that worked great and with a little extra it’s really met the requirements. The users who were stuck migrating from using inboxes to case management were a little stuck in an inbox mindset. This has helped show them cases but a little more tailored to how an inbox works.  Thanks